# How to prevent rain grate on the garden from shifting or collecting debris?

Tags: drainage, gutters

My downspouts go along the wall down to the garden level. I will install rain grates below it to collect the water and direct it to the street.

I will make something like that.

[image]

I think being buried will prevent it from shifting from people walking over it, right?

Do I need to make it above grade to prevent debris from falling into it? I really have no idea about it, as I always seem those grates on floored areas, never on garden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting the downspout directly to an underground pipe will prevent debris from entering the system. It will probably be easier and cheaper to construct as well.

Comment: Thought about that, but I think having about 25 meter of connected pipe without any point of inspection could be disastrous. This is why I want to put one point of inspection (the rain grate in question) in the middle.

Comment: Put in a cleanout. Your cleverness still leaves 25m of pipe underground and adds an opening highly conducive to the entry of debris. Besides, tying directly to the underground is typical for commercial construction when the system is designed by people who design buildings and their systems for a living.

Comment: Hum... I guess you have a point. Here in Brazil we only find Tee type cleanouts (with a treaded cover), but I think I'm going to use a Y juntion and put a pipe with a cap as a cleanout.

Comment: Using 45 degree transitions will make cleaning out the pipe easier and reduce the likelihood of clogs.

Comment: I recently installed a system similar to what you want. I connected 3 of my downspouts to a French drain system I was installing. Each downspout runs into an enclosed pipe with a Y. On the angled Y, a short piece of PVC is fitted and a cleanout cap is fitted on top of that. Allows quick and easy access for future cleaning, yet keeps debris and critters out.